# OnPropertyChangedでXamlにプロパティ変更を通知したい

Tags: c#

BlockColumnPosition1プロパティが変更されたときにXamlにプロパティ変更を通知したいのですが、OnPropertyChangedメソッド内でPropertyChangedがnullになってしまい通知されません。このif文さえ通ってしまえば通知されると思うのですが・・・。
初歩的な質問ですが、ご教示ください。

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GenerateBlock();
    }

    internal enum PropertyNames
    {
        BlockColumnPosition1,
        BlockRowPosition1,
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// ブロック位置（列）
    /// </summary>
    private Int32 blockColumnPosition;

    /// <summary>
    /// ブロック位置（行）
    /// </summary>
    private Int32 blockRowPosition;


    /// <summary>
    /// ブロック位置（列）を取得・設定します。
    /// </summary>
    private Int32 BlockColumnPosition1
    {
        get
        {
            return this.blockColumnPosition;
        }
        set
        {
            this.blockColumnPosition = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(PropertyNames.BlockColumnPosition1.ToString());
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// ブロック位置（行）を取得・設定します。
    /// </summary>
    private Int32 BlockRowPosition1
    {
        get
        {
            return this.blockRowPosition;
        }
        set
        {
            this.blockRowPosition = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(PropertyNames.BlockRowPosition1.ToString());
        }
    }


    private void GenerateBlock()
    {
        BlockColumnPosition1 = 5;
        BlockRowPosition1 = 1;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

第一に`INotifyPropertyChanged`(この場合は`MainWindow`)は作るだけではなく、ビューにバインドしなければなりません。質問のコードでいうと`DataContext`に`this`を設定すると原理的には`PropertyChanged`が使用されます。

次に`MainWindow`は`DependencyObject`を継承していますので、`INotifyPropertyChanged`ではなく依存関係プロパティの仕組みを使うべきです。`Visual Studio`のC#エディター上で`propdp`と入力すると雛形が挿入されますので、それを利用してプロパティを定義してください。

最後に`MainWindow`内で`MainWindow`のプロパティにバインドするのであれば、`RelativeSource`を使用することができます。

なおプロパティ名の`string`を得たい場合は`nameof(BlockColumnPosition1)`のように参照するのが簡単です。さらにいえば`[CallerMemberName]`を使用すると名前を明記する必要はなくなります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
依存関係プロパティを使用することでバインディングすることができました。

DataContextにthisを設定するとうまく動作するのですが、
xaml側でDataContextにMainWindowを設定したり、ResourceにMainWindowを設定すると、
InitializeComponentでStackOverFlowExceptionが発生してしまいます。
自身のクラスをxaml側で上記のように設定すると再帰的にインスタンスが生成されてしまうためだと理解したのですが、
ここでは、ご回答にあったとおり、Model側でDataContextにthisを設定するのが正しいやり方なのでしょうか？

また、今回は依存関係プロパティを使用しましたが、
INotifyPropertyChangedはどういう場合に使用するのが良いのでしょうか。

Comment: @sima 回答にも記載しましたが、`RelativeSource`を使用するのが通常のやり方です。後者に関しては`DependencyObject`は使用できるスレッドに制限がありますし、ただの`DataContext`として使用するには高機能すぎるので通常はコントロールとは無関係な"ビューモデル"専用クラスに`INotifyPropertyChanged`を実装して設定します。